# System slow/unresponsive when Thunderbird is receiving emails with Windows Defender

Tags: windows, thunderbird, windows-defender

When Thunderbird is receiving emails I see a very high CPU usage from Windows Defender, to a point that it hangs and become unresponsive. If I turn off real time protection, it go back to normal. Also, every time I open Thunderbird, it receives all emails over again.
How can I fix this?
I'm on Windows 1709 (16299.431) and Thunderbird 52.7.0

Comment: You can configure Thunderbird to prevent virus check without turning off Defender, which should still offer real-time protection. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_defender-protect_scanning/how-to-exclude-a-filefolder-from-windows-defender/f32ee18f-a012-4f02-8611-0737570e8eee and  https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:Testing:Antivirus_Related_Performance_Issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed Avast and turned off Defender xD

Answer (score 4):

Add [Thunderbird profile directory](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-tb) to exceptions in Defender.

Comment: I suggest adding instructions or a link on how to add exclusions to Defender. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26